# IF statements depending on widget configuration tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Can I create an `if` statement whose condition depends on the text of a button?

For example:

```
if widget.config(text=2):
     btn.config(font=font2)
```

Comment: That condition does not depend on the text of a button.

Comment: Hint: What gets printed if you do `print(widget.config(text=2))`?

Comment: I know Goyo thats the question im asking.....

Comment: Everyone on this community seems so toxic im only trying to learn to program

Comment: @JamesAnderson How's that toxicity? Goyo merely pointed out that it doesn't work the way some other would think that the way your question implies that it does.

Comment: Everyone just seems to try shoot you down - im just trying to learn and get better. Also my questions seem to always get down voted...Why?!! i follow all the rules and provide a logical and structured approach to asking the question. I also include all information necesary

Comment: @JamesAnderson I don't think you've asked good questions on your earlier posts but I think the above question is well asked. It may be lacking research but it is well asked nonetheless. But I also think [Goyo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277590/if-statements-depending-on-widget-configuration-tkinter#comment83538946_48277590) helps better understanding the question. I think if you believe the community here is toxic perhaps try to get more feedback on the questions you had asked earlier by discussing them on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @JamesAnderson Honestly, I do not think that your question is a logical and structired approach to ask "How do I get the text of a tkinter button?" I got distracted by the if's, the conditions and the unrelated code. I am glad somebody else was smarter than I and figured out what you wanted to know.

Comment: Im new to programming, so yes, my knowledge and application isnt the best. So im sorry if you find my questions hard to understand, but i try word it in the best way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.config()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) is only to set value.

To get value you have [.cget()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method)

```
if widget.cget("text") == "2":
```

or dictionary

```
if widget["text"] == "2":
```

---

`text` is string so you have to compare with string `"2"` or you have to convert string to integer

```
if int(widget["text"]) == 2:
```

---

**EDIT:** `cget()` doc shows it returns strings but for `int` and `float` it doesn't convert value to string.

Comment: Actually, `text` can also be an integer, and will also come back as such (not internally converted). Did not know this myself, just tested with Python 3.

Comment: @tobias_k - strange, right now I'm reading doc for [cget()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) and it shows that it returns string. I will have to check it.

Comment: @tobias_k you are right, it keeps integer and float instead of text (but not `True/False`). Tested on Python 2 and 3, using `Label` and `Button`, before `mainloop()` and using `after(100)`

Comment: @furas Interesting: It indeed converts `bool`, but not to `str` but to `int`. Weird. And setting it to `None` has no effect (probably the "ignore-me" default value).